# How to import Java Project completely in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am looking to upload complete Java Project into eclipse, I was wondering if this is possible. Or if I have to create a project and then do it. Regardless im quite lost.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here, and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. One way is via *File>Import*.

If you're importing a directory of Java source code, first create a new project with *File>New>Java Project*. Then use *File>Import*, and choose the import wizard *General>File System*.

If you're importing an existing Eclipse project into your workspace, choose from the import wizard *General>Existing Projects into Workspace*. This is useful if you or someone else has already created the Eclipse project, and you're just adding it to your workspace.